# How to restart an LXC from the LXC itself?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, lxc

I am installing a custom software in the LXC that requires to restart after installation is done,
Is there any way the LXC can access the host's lxc-stop and lxc-start. I dont want to open another terminal to be able to stop and start from the host.

My host is Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried just rebooting the LXC container?  It should have access to "reboot".

Comment: uhhh that worked, I could install reboot in my custom OS and restart using: reboot -f